# xml string value like exponetial becomes float

Tags: c#, xml, schema

I have issue with reading xml value like '111e1' as string type. I m trying to create xsd schema from xml like below using standard C# XmlReader:

```
`
   XmlReaderSettings readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        readerSettings.XmlResolver = null;
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sourcexmlpath, readerSettings))
        {
            XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
            XmlSchemaInference schema = new XmlSchemaInference();
            schemaSet = schema.InferSchema(reader);
            using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(xsdpath))
            {
                foreach (XmlSchema s in schemaSet.Schemas())
                {
                    s.Write(writer);
                }
                writer.Close();
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
`
```

Source xml file:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Document>
      <example>
        <testvalue>34551E10</testvalue>
    </example>
 </Document>
`
```

And I got float type:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
       <xs:element name="Document">
         <xs:complexType>
           <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="example">
               <xs:complexType>
                 <xs:sequence>
                   <xs:element name="testvalue" type="xs:float" />             
                 </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
             </xs:element>
           </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
       </xs:element>
     </xs:schema>`
```

Issue exist if value consist of number and only alone ‘e’ alphabet between of them(problem disappears for other letters), for example:
1e111, 11e11, 111e1 
but we don’t have this problem if letter at the start and end like e11111, 11111e.

How can I prevent reading value as float type? Is it possible?

Comment: In my opinion validating an XML when reading is not necessary.  If the XML is validated when writing it is not necessary to do a schema check when reading.  With XML if the complete file is not read an error will occur due to the closing tags are missing.  So then in your case if you read the file without the schema check you would not get an issue.

Comment: @jdweng but that's the whole point? *"I'm trying to create xsd schema from xml"*.

Comment: You ask following : "How can I prevent reading value as float type? Is it possible?"  My answer is don't check the schema in Reading in c# code.  You are using : XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();  So validate the schema which should pass.  Then read the Xml without schema as string so the floating point number does not change.